# Concurrent for loop in C++

Tags: c++, concurrency

(See the [next](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134078/concurrent-for-loop-in-c-follow-up) iteration.)

I have this easy to use facility that maps input elements to output elements concurrently by the means of a thread pool:

**concurrent.h**:

```
#ifndef FORP_H
#define FORP_H

#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

namespace net {

    namespace coderodde {

        namespace concurrent {
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
             // This is an adhoc concurrent queue used by forp.              //
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            template<class T>
            class queue
            {
                private:

                    struct queue_node
                    {
                        T           m_element;
                        size_t      m_element_index;
                        queue_node* m_next;

                        queue_node(const T& element, const size_t index) :
                            m_element{element},
                            m_element_index{index},
                            m_next{nullptr} 
                            {

                            }
                    };

                    std::mutex m_mutex;
                    queue_node* m_head;
                    queue_node* m_tail;

                public:

                    queue(std::initializer_list<T> list)
                    {
                        m_head = nullptr;
                        size_t index = 0;

                        for (const auto& element : list)
                        {
                            queue_node* new_node = new queue_node(element,
                                                                  index++);

                            if (m_head == nullptr)
                            {
                                m_head = new_node;
                                m_tail = new_node;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                m_tail->m_next = new_node;
                                m_tail = new_node;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    std::tuple<T, size_t, bool> dequeue() 
                    {
                        std::tuple<T, size_t, bool> ret;
                        m_mutex.lock();

                        if (m_head == nullptr)
                        {
                            // The queue is empty.
                            ret = std::make_tuple(T(), 0, false);
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            ret = std::make_tuple(m_head->m_element,
                                                  m_head->m_element_index,
                                                  true);
                            m_head = m_head->m_next;
                        }

                        m_mutex.unlock();
                        return ret;
                    }
            };

            template<class In, class Out>
            void thread_do(net::coderodde::concurrent::queue<In>& input_queue,
                           Out (*process)(In in),
                           std::vector<Out>& output_vector)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    std::tuple<In, size_t, bool> data = input_queue.dequeue();

                    if (std::get<2>(data) == false)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    const In input_element = std::get<0>(data);
                    const size_t input_element_index = std::get<1>(data);

                    Out output_element = process(input_element);
                    output_vector[input_element_index] = output_element;
                }
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
              // This function template implements a concurrent, thread-pool-//
             // based iteration construct.                                  //
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            template<class In, class Out>
            void forp(std::initializer_list<In>& input_list, 
                      Out (*process)(In in),
                      std::vector<Out>& output_vector)
            {
                unsigned thread_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
                std::vector<std::thread> thread_vector;
                thread_vector.reserve(thread_count);
                net::coderodde::concurrent::queue<In> input_queue(input_list);
                output_vector.clear();
                output_vector.reserve(input_list.size());

                for (size_t i = 0; i < input_list.size(); ++i) 
                {
                    output_vector.push_back(Out());
                }

                for (unsigned i = 0; i < thread_count; ++i) 
                {
                    thread_vector.push_back(
                            std::thread(&thread_do<In, Out>, 
                                        std::ref(input_queue), 
                                        std::ref(process), 
                                        std::ref(output_vector)));
                }

                for (std::thread& thread : thread_vector)
                {
                    thread.join();
                }
            }

        } /* namespace concurrent */

    } /* namespace coderodde */

} /* namespace net */

#endif  /* FORP_H */
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "concurrent.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

class CurrentTime {
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock m_clock;

public:

    uint64_t milliseconds() 
    {
        return std::chrono
                  ::duration_cast<std::chrono
                                     ::milliseconds>
              (m_clock.now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    }
};

using net::coderodde::concurrent::forp;
using std::initializer_list;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::stringstream;

static uint64_t fibonacci(uint64_t n)
{
    if (n <= 0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (n == 1) 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}

template<class T>
std::string to_string(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "[";

    if (vec.size() > 0) 
    {
        ss << vec[0];
    }

    for (size_t i = 1; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        ss << ", " << vec[i];
    }

    ss << "]";
    return ss.str();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::initializer_list<uint64_t> fibonacci_task_input_list = 
        { 40, 41, 39, 33, 43, 30, 34, 40, 42, 20, 42, 40, 41 };

    CurrentTime ct;

    vector<uint64_t> result_vector1;
    vector<uint64_t> result_vector2;

    uint64_t start_time = ct.milliseconds();

    for (const int i : fibonacci_task_input_list)
    {
        result_vector1.push_back(fibonacci(i));
    }

    uint64_t end_time = ct.milliseconds();

    cout << "Serial processing in " 
         << (end_time - start_time)
         << " milliseconds.\n";

    start_time = ct.milliseconds();

    net::coderodde::concurrent::forp(fibonacci_task_input_list,
                                     fibonacci,
                                     result_vector2);

    end_time = ct.milliseconds();

    cout << "Parallel processing in "
         << (end_time - start_time)
         << " milliseconds.\n";

    cout << "Serial     result: " << to_string(result_vector1) << "\n";
    cout << "Concurrent result: " << to_string(result_vector2) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**`queue`**

If you look at the `dequeue()` method of the `queue`, it returns also a boolean value indicating whether the queue is still nonempty after actually removing an element from it. I did this out of fear of the following scenario:

Suppose the queue contains only one element. Suppose also that a thread \$T_1\$ asks whether the queue is nonempy. Next, another thread \$T_2\$ asks whether the queue is empty. Next, say, the thread \$T_1\$ pops the last element. Eventually, \$T_2\$ still thinks that the queue is not empty when, in fact, it is.

**Performance figures**

On a dual-core CPU I get the following digits:

> ```
> Serial processing in 20024 milliseconds.
> Parallel processing in 10642 milliseconds.
> Serial     result: [102334155, 165580141, 63245986, 3524578, 433494437, 832040, 5702887, 102334155, 267914296, 6765, 267914296, 102334155, 165580141]
> Concurrent result: [102334155, 165580141, 63245986, 3524578, 433494437, 832040, 5702887, 102334155, 267914296, 6765, 267914296, 102334155, 165580141]
> ```

Since I am not proficient in C++, please, tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few items which caught my eye:

1. I wouldn't have bothered implementing my own queue. Just use a [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) or a plain `std::vector` with an index pointing to the current head element. Saves a bunch of code which you don't have to test and maintain.
2. You shouldn't use the mutex directly, you should use a [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) instead to make sure the mutex gets released automatically when the scope is left.
3. You should reduce the scope of the mutex to a minimum to avoid unnecessary lock contention (in this case probably more of an academic point but still a good habit to get into).

   So the `dequeue` method could look like this:

   ```
   std::tuple<T, size_t, bool> dequeue() 
   {   
       queue_node* item = nullptr;

       {
           std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
           if (m_head != nullptr)
           {
               item = m_head;
               m_head = m_head->next;
           }
       }

       return std::make_tuple(item ? item->m_element : T(),
                              item ? item->m_element_index : 0,
                              item != nullptr);
   }
   ```
4. This:

   > ```
   > output_vector.clear();
   > output_vector.reserve(input_list.size());
   > for (size_t i = 0; i < input_list.size(); ++i) 
   > {
   >     output_vector.push_back(Out());
   > }
   > ```

   Can be replaced with

   ```
    output_vector.clear()
    output_vector.resize(input_list.size());
   ```

   since [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) will automatically insert elements for you if the current size is smaller than the requested size.

---

Update: Actually I just noticed that your `queue` implementation is leaking memory: nodes get `new`-ed but never deleted. Which comes back to my first point :)

Also you're copying the `In` and `Out` elements around a few times when you probably could just move them but I don't do enough day-to-day modern C++ to provide a correct answer on the spot right now. I'll leave that to someone else.

Comment: Is there anything else, such as use of move semantics/rvalue references?

Comment: @coderodde: You could probably move a few things around instead of (implicitly) copying them, I just can't provide a good enough answer  I'm comfortable with on that point right now.