# Concurrent for loop in C++ - follow-up

Tags: c++, concurrency

I have incorporated all the cool points made by [ChrisWue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/30346/chriswue) in the [initial iteration of this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133883/concurrent-for-loop-in-c).

Now, I am not reinventing the wheel for my concurrent queue, but use internally **`std::deque`**. Also, I modified the API of the concurrent **`forp`** construct: now it takes any range specified by means of iterators as the input list.

See what I have:

**concurrent.h**:

```
#ifndef FORP_H
#define FORP_H

#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

namespace net {

    namespace coderodde {

        namespace concurrent {
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
             // This is an adhoc concurrent queue used by forp.              //
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            template<class Iter>
            class queue
            {
                typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type T;

                private:

                    std::deque<T> m_queue;
                    std::size_t   m_index;
                    std::mutex    m_mutex;

                public:

                    queue(Iter begin, Iter end) : m_index{0}
                    {
                        for (Iter i = begin; i != end; ++i) 
                        {
                            m_queue.push_back(*i);
                        }
                    }

                    size_t size() 
                    {
                        return m_queue.size();
                    }

                    std::tuple<T, size_t, bool> dequeue() 
                    {
                        std::tuple<T, size_t, bool> ret;

                        {
                            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

                            if (m_queue.empty())
                            {
                                ret = std::make_tuple(T(), 0, false);
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                ret = std::make_tuple(m_queue.front(), 
                                                      m_index++, 
                                                      true);
                                m_queue.pop_front();
                            }
                        }

                        return ret;
                    }
            };

            template<class InIter, class Out>
            void thread_do(net::coderodde::concurrent::queue<InIter>& input_queue,
                           Out (*process)(typename std::iterator_traits<InIter>::value_type in),
                           std::vector<Out>& output_vector)
            {
                typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InIter>::value_type In;

                while (true)
                {
                    std::tuple<In, size_t, bool> data = input_queue.dequeue();

                    if (std::get<2>(data) == false)
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    const In input_element = std::get<0>(data);
                    const size_t input_element_index = std::get<1>(data);

                    Out output_element = process(input_element);
                    output_vector[input_element_index] = output_element;
                }
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
              // This function template implements a concurrent, thread-pool-//
             // based iteration construct.                                  //
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Side effects: the input range remains intact; output_vector is
            // cleared and populated with the output data.
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            template<class InIter, class Out>
            void forp(InIter begin, InIter end, 
                      Out (*process)(typename std::iterator_traits<InIter>::value_type), 
                      std::vector<Out>& output_vector)
            {
                unsigned thread_count = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
                std::vector<std::thread> thread_vector;
                thread_vector.reserve(thread_count);

                net::coderodde::concurrent::queue<InIter> input_queue(begin, 
                                                                      end);
                output_vector.clear();
                output_vector.resize(input_queue.size());

                for (unsigned i = 0; i < thread_count; ++i) 
                {
                    thread_vector.push_back(
                            std::thread(&thread_do<InIter, Out>, 
                                        std::ref(input_queue), 
                                        std::ref(process), 
                                        std::ref(output_vector)));
                }

                for (std::thread& thread : thread_vector)
                {
                    thread.join();
                }
            }

        } /* namespace concurrent */

    } /* namespace coderodde */

} /* namespace net */

#endif  /* FORP_H */
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "concurrent.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

class CurrentTime {
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock m_clock;

public:

    uint64_t milliseconds() 
    {
        return std::chrono
                  ::duration_cast<std::chrono
                                     ::milliseconds>
              (m_clock.now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    }
};

using net::coderodde::concurrent::forp;
using std::cout;
using std::list;
using std::stringstream;
using std::vector;

static uint64_t fibonacci(uint64_t n)
{
    if (n <= 0) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (n == 1) 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, std::vector<T>& vector)
{
    out << "[";

    if (!vector.empty())
    {
        out << vector[0];
    }

    for (size_t i = 1; i < vector.size(); ++i) 
    {
        out << ", " << vector[i];
    }

    return out << "]";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    list<uint64_t> fibonacci_task_input_list = 
        { 40, 41, 39, 33, 43, 30, 34, 40 };

    CurrentTime ct;

    vector<uint64_t> result_vector1;
    vector<uint64_t> result_vector2;

    uint64_t start_time = ct.milliseconds();

    for (const int i : fibonacci_task_input_list)
    {
        result_vector1.push_back(fibonacci(i));
    }

    uint64_t end_time = ct.milliseconds();

    cout << "Serial processing in " 
         << (end_time - start_time)
         << " milliseconds.\n";

    start_time = ct.milliseconds();

    net::coderodde::concurrent::forp(fibonacci_task_input_list.begin(),
                                     fibonacci_task_input_list.end(),
                                     fibonacci,
                                     result_vector2);

    end_time = ct.milliseconds();

    cout << "Parallel processing in "
         << (end_time - start_time)
         << " milliseconds.\n";

    cout << "Serial result:     " << result_vector1 << "\n";
    cout << "Concurrent result: " << result_vector2 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Any critique is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done a great job using std::deque to implement your concurrent queue (I've read the previous post), here's a bit more advice

1. Include all the headers you need

You're missing `<mutex>` header in `concurrent.h`

2. Avoid unnecessary conversions

   `for (const int i : fibonacci_task_input_list)`

you're converting unsigned int64 to int, should be

```
for (const uint64_t i : fibonacci_task_input_list)
```

3. No mutex in queue and size methods? That might end in undefined behavior, you might consider making them thread safe too (you don't use these methods in different threads, however).
4. More attention to const-correctness. Use `const` whenever you're not modifying data in functions, and indicate which functions are const.

Since you're not modifying the input in `forp` functions, it's better to use `const` iterators

`net::coderodde::concurrent::forp(fibonacci_task_input_list.cbegin(),
     fibonacci_task_input_list.cend(), 
     fibonacci, 
     result_vector2);`

Same here

`template<class T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T>& vector)`

And here

```
size_t size() const
{
    return m_queue.size();
}
```

I hope you get the idea. Meyers does a good job explaining const-correctness in his *Effective C++* series

Answer (score 0):

A few additional things to what has already been mentioned:

1. The `queue` constructor could be simplified since [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/deque) has a constructor which takes an iterator pair:

   ```
   queue(Iter begin, Iter end) : m_index{0}, m_queue(begin, end)
   {
   }
   ```
2. `std::get` return a reference to the element however you effectively store a local copy to pass to the `process` callback function. It would possibly be more efficient to change the `process` callback to take the input element as a reference instead to avoid the local copy.